# Why "to iu na no" instead of "de" or "no"?

Tags: translation, particles

So I'm watching this anime a couple of days ago and one of the characters were describing a group of people. He ended his description with "`GIGN to iu na no inu`". The subtitle says that meant: "**Those dogs of the GIGN**". So I'm wondering is "`GIGN no inu`" or "`GIGN de inu`" wrong? I would think they all mean the same thing.

*GIGN = military police unit

Comment: I do not know the scene and I cannot tell for sure, but probably the subtitle is incorrect.

Answer (score 8):

GIGNと言う名の犬: a (or those) dog(s) by the name of GIGN. na is name.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! So `と言う` can be translated as "to call" as well? I thought that's what `yobu` is for...?

Comment: よぶ mean to literally call out to or invoke. The expression という means "to go by the name of".

Comment: A question that I have though, why is it 名? It sounds like it's saying "The name GIGN's dogs." Why isn't it something like と言う所の犬 or と言う警察の犬?

Comment: @phoenixheart6  N1のN2 does not always translate as "N1's N2", and Xという名のY is pretty common for "(a/those) Y named X". GIGNという犬 would be possible but it has a wider range of possible meanings, so possibly 名 is used to make it clearly that GIGN is the name of the group.

See: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/