# How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?

Tags: particles, particle-の, phrases, relative-clauses

I've read that 日本人の知らない日本語 translates to: "Japanese (language) that Japanese (people) don't know". But I don't understand how or what the の does in that sentence. If I'm not mistaken 知らない日本語 could mean "Japanese language that (x) don't know" or "even unknown Japanese". But I don't get how the 日本人の fits into the translation.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In your example, 日本人の知らない is a relative clause, equivalent in meaning to 日本人が知らない.  This clause as a whole modifies 日本語, so it means *the Japanese that Japanese people don't know*.

---

In relative clauses, the subject particle が can be replaced with の:

> 1. ジョン**が**買った本
> 2. ジョン**の**買った本
>
> *The book John bought*

This is true in *double-subject constructions* as well:

> 1. ジョン**が**背**が**高い理由
> 2. ジョン**が**背**の**高い理由
> 3. ジョン**の**背**が**高い理由
> 4. ジョン**の**背**の**高い理由
>
> *The reason John is tall*

But you can't replace が with の if there's a direct object marked with を:

> 1. ジョン**が**本**を**買った店
> 2. *ジョン**の**本**を**買った店 *(ungrammatical)*
>
> *The store where John bought the book*

Comment: Maybe I am beating the dead horse, but ジョンの本を買った店 can mean "The store someone bought the book written by John."

Comment: When I say "ungrammatical", to be more precise I really mean "ungrammatical with the intended interpretation".  That is, the process of nominative-genitive conversion is ungrammatical here due to the transitivity restriction, even though there may be an alternative source for the example in question, as you point out.  Thank you for your comment!

Comment: In the last two sentences using を, they both strike me as grammatical, but the meaning shifts -- sentence 2 parses out to *"the store that bought John's book"*.

Comment: Please see my comment above :-)

Comment: Interestingly enough, `が` can be used in 文語 Japanese where in modern, oral Japanese only `の` is usually acceptable (`我々が心`), as is obvious in a bunch of place names (written `ヶ` -- e.g. 関ケ原, 霞ヶ関 etc). Maybe `が` and `の` where more broadly interchangeable in different times / regions, but only clearly remained so in the case of relative clauses in modern / standard Japanese ?

Answer (score 18):

It's just standard GA-NO conversion.

> ［日本人が知らない］日本語
>   'Japanese that [Japanese don't know]'

Comment: In more precise terms: の can act like a subject (nominative) particle in descriptive (attirbutive/relative) clauses.