# の / が equivalence in this haiku from Bashō

Tags: grammar, particle-の, particle-が, haiku

I am aware of the equivalence of the particules の and が in the case of a relative clause (cf. for instance [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e)).

However, the following haiku does not seem to fall into this category:

> 枯枝に　烏のとまりけり　秋の暮

Does the use of の bring a special nuance here? One answer on
[Why is the particle の used instead of が in these phrases?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/why-is-the-particle-%e3%81%ae-used-instead-of-%e3%81%8c-in-these-phrases) suggests that it could shift the focus on the verb/action rather than on the subject, but given the use of the auxiliary けり that describes the action as completed, this would be a very subtle nuance.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28214/5010 and https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/93246/5010