# 「輪郭の柔らかな瓜実顔」Why is it 「の」instead 「が」？

Tags: grammar, particle-の

Is this an idiomatic thing? Or an exception? Maybe both are possible?

Comment: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9749

Comment: Thank you. Now, should I delete this? I'm not sure how to mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @J.Doe No need to delete. This question will eventually be marked as a duplicate by high-reputation users.