# What does 手のだしょうがなかった mean

Tags: translation, meaning

I would be very thankful, if someone could help me figure out the meaning of the second part of the sentence below

> これは地元住民とT大OBの反対によるもので、業者としても手のだしょうがなかったのだ。

The sentence is the explanation why despite other new shops Pachinko Salons cannot open in the area.
I would loosly translate it as

*That was due to the resistance of the local residents and alumnis of T university, so that even if someone wanted to he had no chance*

but I am mostly guessing the second part. What is the meaning of 手 in combination with のだ and what function does のだ have here? としても means *even if* right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it's not だし**ょ**う but だしよう (with non-small よ). It's 出し様 in kanji if it helps you.

- として here roughly means "as ～" in the sense of "from the standpoint of ～". も is "also".
- [手を出す is a common set phrase](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%89%8B%E3%82%92%E5%87%BA%E3%81%99) which means "to get involved", "to interfere", etc.
- `pre-masu-form + よう` forms a noun that means "a way to ～", "possibility of ～". In particular, ～ようがない is a set phrase "there is no ～ing" or "to be impossible to ～".
- のだ at the end is a plain explanatory-の followed by だ.

> 業者としても手の出し【だし】ようがなかったのだ。
>   (It is that) even the company/dealer had no way to interfere.

Related:

- [Meaning/Breakdown of 答えの出しようのない疑問](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29946/5010)
- [The significance of の in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58044/5010)