# How is 「の」 used in 終わりのない?

Tags: particle-の

I understand that 「の」 can be used to indicate possession or to change a noun to a modifier for another noun. But neither of those seems to be the case here.

What usage of 「の」 is being used here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

終わりのない is not a complete sentence. This phrase can be used as a *relative clause* which modifies another noun.

> - 終わりのない話 a story which has no end; a never-ending story
> - 終わりがない話 a story which has no end; a never-ending story

As you can see, this type of の is a subject marker (just like が) which can be used only in relative clauses.

See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)