# Why が instead of の in 人が話す声が熊に聞こえると?

Tags: particle-の, particle-が

I've read the news that reads:

> 人**が**話す声が熊に聞こえると、熊が近くに来なくなります。

Why が not の in this case? Is there a convention or a particular rule? Or do they have subtle differences?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you confuse 話す声 with 話し声? If it were 話し声 instead of 話す声, it would have to be 人**の**話し声 indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your current level of knowledge, so let me start with the basics.

人が話す is a ([gapless](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010)) relative clause that modifies 声. 人**が**話す声 and 人**の**話す声 are interchangeable, and they both mean "the sound of someone talking". This phenomenon is known as [ga-no conversion](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010). There are [exceptions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42570/5010), but basically が and の are [surprisingly similar](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/93246/5010) in a relative clause.

---

If you already understand all of this, but still feel 人**の**話す声が熊に聞こえると is better, then yes, I agree. In this particular case, to avoid using が twice in close proximity within the same sentence, I think it would have been slightly better to say 人**の**話す声**が**熊に聞こえると. But this is a very minor issue that would hardly ever be pointed out as unnatural, and there's usually no need to worry about it. The original sentence is perfectly accurate and natural as-is.