# Why does the sentence "Omo wa anata to tomoni oraremasu" use "anata to"?

Tags: grammar

So I've changed the question since it was a segmentation fault.

Why did the sentence use "anata to"?

Tomo means together, doesn't to already means together?

Comment: A lot of your questions arise from segmentation errors/over-reliance on romaji. I think it's been suggested before in other threads, but I think a better understanding of the writing system might better inform your future questions.

Comment: Sorry I guess it was a segmentation fault. Can you recheck the question I edited it. I can read hiragana now, and some kanji but I can't write them yet. @jogloran

Comment: Writing kana is a matter of making a couple small setting changes to whatever device you're using. It shouldn't take much.

Comment: By not write I mean handwriting, I can type them pretty easily. The problem is that this        にほn n doesn't change to its kana form and n doesn't appear in the suggestions I dunno why prolly cuz of my keyboard. Plus I usually just copy paste from the source material when I ask questions so I copy paste the romaji one since the kanji I can read can only be counted on one hand although I'm slowly increasing that. @Leebo

Comment: @RommelBagasina If you want to write ん write 'nn'. N itself doesn't change because for example に and んい are different

Comment: `Omo wa anata to tomoni oraremasu` <-- "**Shu** wa ..." no? Should be 「[主]{しゅ}はあなたと共におられます」, not [主]{おも}は...

Comment: In English, *with* and *together with* are used similarly without much difference in meaning, aren't they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

あなたとともに is "together with you", where あなた is "you", と is "with", and ともに is "together". I don't think this is a redundant expression in both English and Japanese. Just saying しゅはともにおられます would make sense with the aid of a context, but it may sound ambiguous or weaker. Without あなたと, the Lord might be together with someone entirely different!

By the way, if 主 refers to Christian God, its correct reading is しゅ, not おも. Please see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/46854/5010). (おも means "main" as in main dish.)