# What does の mean in 形のない花?

Tags: nuances, syntax, relative-clauses

I came across a 東方 remix called 形のない花, which translates (apparently) to "Shapeless Flower".

Now, I see the words 形、ない、花 for, of course, "Shape", "Not", and "Flower" respectively. However, I'm at a total loss when it comes to what exactly the syntax is supposed to be doing.

Is ない a noun or adjective? Is の a possessive or a が in a relative clause? I'm at a loss for this stuff and am wanting some help; as I simply don't know where to start, even if I can understand the meaning.

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Answer (score 0):

ない is adjective

の is が

形(subject) が(verb) ない(adjective) 花(noun)