# Is this sentence right?　コーヒーがおいしい喫茶店{きっさてん}へ行きたいです。

Tags: syntax, relative-clauses

Can I transform this sentence:

> **おいしいコーヒーがある**喫茶店{きっさてん} へ行きたいです。

into this sentence:

> **コーヒーがおいしい**喫茶店{きっさてん}へ行きたいです。

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Both sentences are grammatical and they mean just about the same thing.

One thing I would like to mention, though, since this is a learning site is the fact that native speakers are taught from early on that the particle 「**が**」 in a relative clause sounds "better and nicer" if changed to 「**の**」.  Some teachers are more strict than the others on this.  Personally, almost all of my own teachers in elementary school were in the の-sect, so I myself am also.  Old habits die hard.

Thus, depending on the person you ask, you might be told to make that change in both sentences even though they are already "correct" if grammatical correctness is all that matters.

Highly related:

[What's the grammar behind ヤカンのある部屋?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54478/whats-the-grammar-behind-%e3%83%a4%e3%82%ab%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ae%e3%81%82%e3%82%8b%e9%83%a8%e5%b1%8b)

To sum up, you ***can*** say:

> 「おいしいコーヒー(**が** or **の**)ある喫茶店{きっさてん}」
>
> 「コーヒー(**が** or **の**)おいしい喫茶店」
>
> 「アタシ(**が** or **の**)好{す}きなCD」

But you ***cannot*** say:

> 「あの喫茶店にはおいしいコーヒー**の**ある。」 Only using 「が」 is correct.

Comment: I am also a native speaker of Japanese, but my Japanese teachers said nothing about this in my entire school life. Personally I recognized "ga-no conversion" only after I started to visit this site. So maybe this depends on when and where we received Japanese education.

Comment: From your perspective, is there a difference in meaning between using が and の in relative clauses? I remember someone saying in certain situations it limits the context, but I don't clearly remember where they got the explanation.