# の replacing が in subordinate clauses

Tags: nuances, particle-の

I've read in [this article](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/05/no-subject-marker.html#tricky-parts) that の can replace が when used in a subordinate clause.

For example, 耳が長いエルフ is the same as 耳の長いエルフ, evidently. However, this article doesn't describe any difference in nuance between these two options. Is there any?

Comment: Related or duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54478/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27456/9831

Comment: The reason is to reduce the number of がs in the sentence like 耳が長いエルフが好き -> 耳の長いエルフが好き. You keep the が in the outer one.

Comment: ^ じゃ「耳**の**長いエルフ**の**絵を描きます」とかだったら「耳**が**長いエルフの絵を描きます」にします？

Comment: ^ That's another possibility with the same reasoning and you also keep the outer one, just の in this case.