# Regarding がある/のある

Tags: grammar

I'm writing somthing for my Japanese class currently, and I wrote 「おいしい食べ物のあるレストラン」and I thought that when ある was modifying a noun you could change it to の but my teacher corrected it to が. Are there exceptions to changing it to のある?

Comment: `my teacher corrected it to が` -- へえ・・？　「の」でいいと思うけど・・ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Comment: There are lots of restrictions on ga-no conversion, but this isn't one of them. https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5728dfa81bbee0da7943b811/t/57999461e4fcb532086bf67f/1469682786689/01-MiyagawaEL.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There are restrictions, but they relate to register. In this case の is slightly higher-register than が, but both are grammatically correct. (FYI I think a more natural phrasing wd simply be おいしい食べ物のレストラン.)

Comment: `a more natural phrasing wd simply be おいしい食べ物のレストラン` <-- う～ん？？　「 **食べ物のおいしい**レストラン」の間違いでは？ 「おいしい食べ物のレストラン」より、OPの「おいしい食べ物の/があるレストラン」のほうが自然ですし。　(Maybe you meant to type **食べ物のおいしい**レストラン, no?  I don't think your おいしい食べ物のレストラン would sound more natural than OP's おいしい食べ物のあるレストラン.)

Comment: おっしゃる通りですが、あくまでも元の質問の形に近いバリエーションとしての提言でした。