# Sentence Structure JLPT question 「日本語がかんたんな本」

Tags: syntax, particle-が, jlpt, relative-clauses

Please help. 
I found this question on the N5 practice exam:

> ヤン 「私はこの本を買います。アンナさんはどんな本がいいですか。」
>   アンナ 「 私はもうすこし ( _  _  ☆  _) がいいです。」
>
> A. 本
>    B. かんたんな
>    C. が
>    D. 日本語

Please explain why 日本語がかんたんな本が is the structure... why not もう少しが日本語かんたんな本? What is the rule followed? Why is there two が?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「日本語がかんたんな本」 is a noun phrase where 「日本語がかんたんな」 is a relative clause modifying 「本」. Its non-relative version would be:

> (その)本は、日本語がかんたんです。
>   *lit.* As for the book, Japanese is simple.
>   → The book is written in simple Japanese.

「もう少し」("a little more") is an adverb that modifies the na-adjective 「かんたんな」("simple").

You can parse your example this way:

> ［（もう少し）日本語がかんたんな］本がいいです。
>   *lit.* "I'd like / prefer a book [whose Japanese is (a little) simple(r)]"
>   → I'd like / prefer a book with a little simpler Japanese / a book written in a little simpler Japanese

You can rephrase it as 「もう少し日本語**の**かんたんな本」. (For more on this, you could refer to [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12829/9831).)

Some example phrases using this pattern:

> 「[髪]{かみ}がきれいな人」（「髪のきれいな人」） "a person with beautiful hair"　
>   「[鼻]{はな}が[長]{なが}い[動物]{どうぶつ}」（「鼻の長い動物」） "an animal with a long trunk"

Comment: Thank you very much  and yes I have been wondering why the の is omitted. Will read the link you posted thanks.

Comment: Follow up question. I just read about relative clauses (still cannot get it) ... so the function of the relative clause is as an adj of the 本?

Comment: Yes, it's an adjectival clause. It modifies/describes the noun 本 adjectivally.

Answer (score 1):

日本語がかんたんな本がいいです。
There are two が because there are two sentences.

First sentence:
本がいいです。
A book is good.

Second sentence:
日本語がかんたんな本
A book which has simple Japanese.