# What does ことがないように express?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, expressions

I've come across this sentence quite a few months ago, but I never understood the meaning of "こと**が**ないように", I've searched and found about こと**の**ないように, but I think it has not the same meaning.

This is the sentence:

> 松野の家名を汚す**ことがないように**お願いしますよ。

The translation I found is:

> "Please, do not do anything that can dishonor the name of Matsuno family"

Comment: This has several components, which do you understand, and which don't you?

Comment: Possible source: http://www.taxcom.co.jp/column/ichidaiki/ichidaiki001.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 松野の家名を汚すこと**が**ないようにお願いしますよ。
>   松野の家名を汚すこと**の**ないようにお願いしますよ。

Both are correct and mean the same thing. (～こと**の**ないように sounds a tiny bit more formal to me..)

ように is the continuative form of the auxiliary ようだ. ようだ comes from the noun [様]{よう} + the copula だ. Since the よう is originally a noun, it can act like a noun and can be a head noun of a relative clause.

> ｛松野の家名を汚すこと**が/の**ない｝よう(に)
>   *lit.* (in) the way/manner [that you don't dishonor the name of the Matsuno family]
>   → so as not to dishonor the name of the Matsuno family

You could see 松野の家名を汚すことがない as a relative clause that modifies the noun よう.
It has the same structure as:

> ｛日本人**が/の**知らない｝日本語
>   the Japanese language [that Japanese people don't know]

For more on the が-の conversion, see: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831)

Comment: I got it now, thank you so much for answering!