# Difference between が, の, and no particle

Tags: particle-の, particle-が

Take a look at the lyrics of [テルーの唄](http://www.utamap.com/showkasi.php?surl=B17197):

> 人影絶えた野の道
>   ...
>   虫の囁く草原

As I understand it, both 人影絶えた and 虫の囁く are relative clauses that modify 野の道 and 草原, respectively. But why don't we use the particle が here like:

> 人影が絶えた野の道
>      ...
>      虫が囁く草原

When should I use の or omit the particle?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e

Comment: As for omitting the particle, I suspect that is more to do with making the words fit the rhythm of the song rather than a grammatical consideration.

Answer (score 2):

の can be used in place of が in relative clauses, although there are some exceptional rules. The basic rule of ga-no conversion is described in this question: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)

When ga-no conversion happens, が and の are almost the same in modern prose, but some sources say the use of の is gradually declining. I personally feel が sounds slightly more explicit and objective, whereas の is more "traditional" and has a subtle aesthetic quality suitable in lyrics and product titles. I remember my math teacher always encouraged the use of が because it sounded more academic and objective to him. (The difference is very subtle, and not everyone would agree with me. Please do not overthink this.)

In classical Japanese, a subject marker was not necessary, and you could directly join a subject and a predicate (e.g., 春が過ぎて = 春過ぎて). This is not found in modern formal prose, but you can still see a similar pattern in lyrics and fixed expressions. Especially in this song, the whole lyrics basically follow the haiku-like 7-5 pattern (七五調), so adding が or の to 人影絶えた would break the good rhythm of the song.