# の particle replacing が particle

Tags: particle-の, particle-が

I came across this sentence:

彼女はとても教養のある人ですね

Why is の particle used here rather then が particle. I am probably missing the needed grammar to understand this sentence. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-の-work-in-日本人の知らない日本語 .