# "魅力ある人" vs "魅力がある人" vs "魅力のある人"

Tags: nouns

I saw all occurrences. To me '魅力(noun)+が+ある'(simplified clause) + 人(noun) sounds more correct.

Can someone help on the differences:
魅力ある人
魅力がある人
魅力のある人

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%E3%81%AE-work-in-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E for the last two mentioned, they would have nearly identical meaning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

魅力のある人 and 魅力がある人 are interchangeable because there is a grammatical rule called ga-no conversion. Note that this only applies when 魅力がある works as a relative clause modifying a noun. 彼には魅力がある is fine but 彼には魅力のある is ungrammatical. See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)

魅力ある人 is relatively less common but correct. It sounds a little literary because it uses the grammar of old Japanese, where the subject marker が was rarely used. There are some fixed, literary, adjective-like expressions in the form of `noun + ある` ("-ful") or `noun + なき/ない` ("-less"):

- 心ある人 hearty person
- 心なき人／心ない人 heartless person
- 形ある物 material/tangible thing
- 形なき物 immaterial/intangible/formless thing
- 家なき子 *Sans Famille* (novel) / homeless child
- 余りある食料 a great abundance of food (more than necessary)

These are basically fixed adjective-like expressions, and new ones are rarely coined. You have to remember which noun can take this form one by one.