# What is the purpose of のある in 人気のある?

Tags: adjectives

The full sentence was 人気のある情報を見る, found on a button. Why would のある instead of for instance な

Comment: It means the same than 人気がある. Does it help? As for why and how this が can be replaced by の, it has been answered before [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/32952)

Comment: @jarmanso7 I understand the の/が replacement, the part that confuses me is why is ある used with 人気? Does it just mean favorite? Can other adjectives also be used like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

人気 works both as a noun ("popularity") and as a no-/na-adjective ("popular"). The following sentences mean the same thing:

*"Pokémon is popular with children."*

- ポケモンは子供に人気です。
- ポケモンは子供に人気があります。

English speakers don't usually say "there is popularity", but Japanese speakers do say 人気がある for whatever reason. Both sentences are very common and I don't even know which is more common.

Naturally, you can construct relative clauses from them. The following noun phrases mean the same thing:

*"a Pokémon which is popular with children"*

- 子供に人気なポケモン
- 子供に人気のポケモン
- 子供に人気があるポケモン
- 子供に人気のあるポケモン