# Difference between using が and の in these sentences

Tags: grammar, particles

I have two examples here where the particle の is used where I would've used が so I was hoping someone could explain if there's a difference in these instances, or if either is acceptable.

主人のいない侍

顔のない男

Is there a reason の is used in place of が/is the meaning the same if one is used over the other?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e)

Answer (score 1):

In short, relative (adjectival) clauses (that is, short phrases modifying a noun), の can replace が. There's really not much to say about it, other than that it is only used in very short clauses (usually subject の verb-or-adjective, and that's it), and if it's ambiguous with a "possessive" の than you either can't use it, or it has to "work either way".

You also wouldn't use it if there's any emphasis on the thing before が - the construction kind of makes the whole sub-phrase sound like a single adjective (I mean, that's what it is already, regardless of の vs が - but it sounds more flat with the の, I think)

Answer (score 0):

Both of の　and が　is OK to understand above two sentence.
The reason is because 侍 have 主人, and 男 have 顔(usually).

But sometimes の and　が　can't be used.
〇 Aさんが私に書いた地図
✕  Aさんの私に書いた地図　→because 地図 doesn't belong to Ａさん

〇 Bさんが私にくれた時計
✕  Bさんの私にくれた時計 →because 時計 doesn't belong to B さん

Comment: I don't think the "have" explanation really works for this case. Sure, in this case the verbs being used are いる/ある which are like "to have", but there are plenty of cases where you can use の like this and it has nothing to do with "having". 子犬の食った宿題, for instance. It's not the dog's homework. Or 背の高い人 - are you going to say the shoulders/back "has" the tallness? This is not the possessive の, but the が-replacing の for sub-clauses.