# What is the use of the first の in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, particle-の

"色**の**薄いものと濃いものを両方使うときれいに見えます。" I thought this was the case where の substitutes が but this is not a relative clause. I'd just like to know about this particular use of の.

Comment: What makes you say it's not a relative clause?

Comment: I'm not very well-versed in grammar... every time I read explanations on "relative clauses in Japanese", the examples have verb qualifying a noun and then the topic particle, so I assumed relative clauses were like メガネをかけている女は(...)

Comment: 薄い is an い adjective, yes, and not a verb, but an い adjective can serve in the same role within a clause. 色が薄い is a complete clause, and then it modifies もの, so you've got a relative clause. There are no other requirements beyond that.

Comment: @Leebo ^ Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Leebo has mentioned, this is a relative clause. In other words,

> 色**の**薄いものと濃いものを両方使うときれいに見えます。

and

> 色**が**薄いものと濃いものを両方使うときれいに見えます。

pretty much mean the same thing.  [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/29327) is a good explanation of が and の usage.