# What's the difference between 【Noun + が + いadj】 and 【Noun + の + Verb】

Tags: grammar, verbs, i-adjectives

I was reading and I found the next sentence:

> そこから動きの鈍った魔物がもぞもぞと入り込んでくる

And I had that question, What's the difference between that and saying

> そこから動きが鈍い魔物がもぞもぞと入り込んでくる

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as a basic rule, が and の are interchangeable in relative clauses (with a few restrictions). 動き**の**鈍った魔物 and 動き**が**鈍った魔物 are totally interchangeable, and 動き**が**鈍い魔物 and 動き**の**鈍い魔物 are totally interchangeable, too. See: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010)

Then what's the difference between 動きが**鈍った**魔物 and 動きが**鈍い**魔物? Simply, the former refers to monsters that are usually quick but have temporarily slowed down for some reason, while the latter tends to refer to monsters that are always slow. In other words, in the former case, the sentence means those monsters are tired, injured, or under some weakening magic.