# Meaning of koto + no together in particular sentence

Tags: grammar, literature

I'm trying to read a bit more in Japanese and I bought a Japanese reader. There is this passage of The Spider's Thread by Akutagawa Ryuunosuke that says:

> ここへきてから何年に出した事のない声で「しめた。しめた」と笑いました。

I get the basic gist of the sentence is "He laughed and said "I got it!" with a voice he hadn't used in many/some years since he came here".

The thing is, I'm having a hard time understanding the ことのない part of the sentence. I know koto and nai can be used to make a verb a noun (the voice that hasn't been used in years) but I'm getting messed up by the fact that both 事　and の　are used back to back. If anyone could clarify this for me I would be very thankful

Comment: Possible duplicate [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The noun 声 is modified by ここへきてから何年にも出した事**が**ない. In a clause that modifies a noun, が is often changed to の.