# What's the difference between が and の in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particles, particle-の, particle-が

On Kana-Boon's スノーグローブ (Snow Globe) song, there are two versions of the same sentence:

> 君**が**好きな白い雪になろう
>
> 君**の**好きな白い雪になろう

What is the difference between these two sentences? Does の have a possession meaning, like "Your white snow that you like"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both mean the same:

> I will be the white snow that you like.

There is not much difference here. In a clause that modifies a noun, the subject marker が is often changed to の, especially when it is near the noun.

However, since the predicate is 好き in this case, the first sentence with が could have a second meaning:

> I will be the white snow that likes you.

In this interpretation, 君 would be the object of the verb "to like" in English. (好き is an adjective in Japanese.)

Maybe this was intended.

Comment: +1 for pointing out something I hadn't considered to feel in the first sentence, the notion that "you" is the object of affection, not merely the snow.  That made my day brighten just to imagine.  Beautiful words.