# Difference between ことのできる and ことができる

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I came across this sentence while reading a visual novel (Clannad):

> そして、クラスの中で、唯一俺が心を許して**話すことのできる**人間だった。

Why does this sentence use こと**の**できる instead of こと**が**できる for the potential form? Does it change the nuance of the meaning in any way, or are の and が just interchangeable here?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/12829/30454

Comment: Thank you Eddie, it makes sense now.