# Why choose の over が?

Tags: word-choice, particles

What is the difference between using の and using が in these two expressions?

- 興味がある
- 興味のある

The full sentence:

それは学生にとって興味のある問題だと思う。

I understand the meaning, but it seems to me you could replace that の with a が and produce exactly the same sentence.

Why choose one over the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/9831

Comment: @Chocolate Thanks. I found that thread before posting my own; it actually does not answer my question though. I'm trying to figure out if there is a reason to choose one particle over the other. I know _how_ to use both particles, and I know they mean the same thing in a relative clause. But how does one know when の sounds better or more natural?

Comment: @SevenOclock Is it confusing? I explicitly state that I already know the meaning and want to know why one would choose の over が other. The fact that there is a choice to be made implies there is a difference.

Answer (score 3):

In the attributive usage, the が/の are generally interchangeable.

- それは学生にとって興味のある問題だと思う。
- それは学生にとって興味**が**ある問題だと思う。

Both are fine.

As a predicate 興味のある is not acceptable.

- 私はその問題に興味**が**ある。
- ×私はその問題に興味**の**ある。

Practically it would be better to remember 興味のある is a phrase meaning *of interest*.

---

興味のある looks more common to me than 興味がある (as a modifier).

Comment: Great answer, thanks.