# Using のいない rather than がいない for a noun modifying clause

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-が, japanese-to-english

https://twitter.com/Rika_Furude0821/status/1604386169034153985/photo/1

In this comic, 梨花 is being told

> "梨花ちゃん**の**いない未来なんて御免だ"

Which I think means:
"I'm so sorry for a future without Rika".

How came it's not "梨花ちゃん**が**いないがいない未来なんて御免だ".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/45489)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%e3%81%ae-work-in-%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e4%ba%ba%e3%81%ae%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e) BTW, this ごめんだ is not "I'm sorry" but "not wanted". The sentence means "A future without Rika is not acceptable (to me)."

Comment: Or more literally, "A future in which Rika does not exist is unacceptable".

Answer (score 2):

Very difficult question
According to one Japanese dictionary, "の" is more literal than "が".

Some people feel that "が" enhances XX in "XXがいない未来" than "の".
However, "が" is used primarily to refer to the Subject.

Therefore, Some people think that "の" should be recommended to avoid being misunderstood as the subject.(especially, in short sentence)

But,some people think that "の" has so many uses that it should be used as little as possible.

Conclusion：It depends on the individual's preference

Now, in Japan, more people use "が" than "の" (広辞苑)

I think the difference is very small.

https://finetune32.wordpress.com/2017/03/23/%e6%a0%bc%e5%8a%a9%e8%a9%9e%e3%81%ae%e4%bd%bf%e3%81%84%e5%88%86%e3%81%91%ef%bc%9a%e3%80%8c%e3%81%8c%e3%80%8d%e3%81%a8%e3%80%8c%e3%81%ae%e3%80%8d/

p.s. I like ひぐらしのなく頃に！