# What does 作品の目的とする表現 actually mean?

Tags: meaning, translation, syntax

> これは、作品の目的とする表現に従った演出の結果が見るものに「リアリティ」を感じさせた場合においてであるが、演者が自身の人格や感情を演技の媒介にする（つまり「素」をだしたような）ものは、それが演者の「リアル」であっても、視聴者がリアリティと感じられるかには困難がつきまとう。

For context this is the on the definition of the word 迫真 and I am baffled by the usage of の目的とする here. Does it mean

1: the work intended expression or

2: expressions that takes the work as a mark or a guide ????

Answer (score 1):

The の is a subject marker.

- [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/45489)

So it is equivalent 作品が目的とする表現, where 作品が目的とする is a relative clause modifying 表現: *an expression which the work aims at*.