# noun + の + verb + こと VS noun + を + verb + こと

Tags: syntax, particle-の, particle-を, particle-こと

I was just wondering if the following sentence was correct:

> 日本語の話すこと

It doesn't sound wrong to me, as the whole「話すこと」part becomes a noun, but I'm not quite sure.

I think the more standard way to say it would be:

> 日本語を話すこと

Then the verb 「話す」is not a part of the noun「こと」

What do you think?

Comment: It would help to know what you want to say in English.

Answer (score 1):

日本語を話すこと is "the act of speaking Japanese". This is a well formed, perfectly normal phrase (not sentence).

日本語の話すこと is grammatical but weird. If we treat の as the possessive particle then we have "the act of speaking which is the Japanese language". This makes no sense to me. I cannot think of a way to parse it that does make sense.

If we treat の as the subject particle ([see this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12825/how-does-the-%E3%81%AE-work-in-%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%89%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E)) then we have "the act of the Japanese language speaking". I could possibly imagine this in some poetic context but I don't think you would find it in everyday life.

Comment: I'm missing my weekly does of Harry Potter a la Japanese. :-)

Comment: @A.Ellett Sorry, been too busy to read any further this week :-( Next chapter is devoted to Quidditch, so not too exciting.

Comment: And now I notice I can't spell "dose" correctly, sigh.  Well, I'll look forward to your next installment.

Comment: I love "the act of speaking which is the Japanese language"!  The concept of speaking itself is the language of Japan