# What is the function of the particle ~の in this sentence?

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-こと

I came across this sentence while I was studying: 人間は話すことのできる唯一の動物だ。

I understand the meaning of the whole sentence, but I don't know why both 〜こと and 〜の are present. From my understanding, both have the ability to convert the plain form of a verb to a noun (ie. 遊ぶのが好き、遊ぶことが好き).

Is there another usage of the particle の that I'm missing here?

Comment: の here is essentially a subject marker: [How does the の work in 「日本人の知らない日本語」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825) Or you may better think ことができる and ことのできる both mean *can*.