# のs Everywhere....Why?

Tags: translation, particles, particle-の

I have to translate the following for my intro Japanese class.

```
私は、去年、名古屋市内の静かな所にある庭つきの三階建ての窓の大きい住みやすい家を買いました。
```

I think it means the following.

```
Last year, I bought a yard/garden including, 3 story, large window, easy to live in
house which is in a quiet place inside the City of Nagoya.
```

However, I feel like there are のs in weird places.

1. First の - I can rationalize this as the interior of the City of Nagoya "owning" the place.
2. Second の - Not really sure on this one. Maybe it's just part of the garden "attached" structure?
3. Third and forth の - These I REALLY don't understand. How they work in conjunction with the 窓. I think it's the windows that are big. But maybe it's the house and the house just has regular windows? I just don't know.

Can someone explain to me what all these のs are doing? Thank you :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [So-called の-adjectives - how does の \*really\* work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/so-called-%e3%81%ae-adjectives-how-does-%e3%81%ae-really-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to offer a little less technical explanation.

Don't think of these の particles as being possession. Think of them as one noun modifying another. We take the first and mix its flavor with the second one, if you will. So for example:

> 名古屋市内の静かな所にある庭つきの三階建ての窓の大きい住みやすい家を買いました。

It seems a little fuzzy but this is essentially packing a whole bunch of descriptions of 家 into one sentence. It's awkwardly long and that's kind of the point, just like the English translation being a long list of characteristics is also long and unwieldy. Let's take another approach from the inside out looking at how these の are working.

At the core, we have 住みやすい家. No particle trickery here. A house that's 'easy to live in.' Adding on to that we have [窓の大きい]住みやすい家. This is referring to a livable house *with big windows*. If we mix the meanings together the meaning is clear. In this particular situation the の functions like the particle が. This is a slightly older pattern that still shows up in some places, like 髪の長い女の子, or a girl with long hair.

Moving out from the original nucleus of 住みやすい家 and adding on more and more of the ～の phrases adds on more of that style of modification. So next you'd add 三階建ての. This is what Darius is talking about with the である stuff. You would normally want to say 三階建てです, but you can't use だ/です to connect to another word. So we use である to allow the copula to connect to other things, and the の in this place has the same role as that である.

So from there we can continue adding extra characteristics. Lump all the previous ones together and let's just call it 家. So now we have just added the idea of 3 floors to it. Then to our new 家 language blob we add 庭付き to talk about its yard/garden in a fashion similar to the 三階建て.

Note that the 静かなところにある uses に and not の. This is because の does not refer to a location. If we were to say 静かな所のある then we would say that the house (or possibly the 庭, it's a little ambiguous) *has* a quiet place within it, as in the の/が pattern I mentioned above.

I would also suggest that 名古屋市内の静かな所 should be interpreted separately as its own unit. This livable house with big windows and three floors and a garden is *in a quiet place in Nagoya*. Perhaps you can call this a genitive の, or what you have been associating it with as the *possessive* の.

This is a very basic explanation and I am not striving for technical precision down to the most minute detail. Nevertheless, if you think of の as a general idea of noun modification rather than just possession it will start to make more sense.

Comment: I am not too familiar with grammatical terms, so this helped. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. The genitive marker is not just for possession.
2. の is not just the genitive marker.

Here are all the のs (with their subjects pulled in closer):

- `［名古屋市内の］家`: this is a descriptive genitive, like "children's clothes" -- more to describe than to show possession
- `［庭つきの］家`: this is not a genitive at all (IMO), it is an adnominal form of the copula; (try replacing it with である)
- `［三階建ての］家`: again, adnominal copula; (try replacing it with である)
- `［窓の大きい］家`: this の is a が which has undergone GA-NO conversion which is possible due to it being a relative clause; (try replacing it with が)

Comment: Could you describe what the "adnominal copula" is?

Comment: だ when it's modifying a noun instead of at the end of a sentence.

Comment: But the だ changes to a の?

Comment: Yes. It can also turn into である to perform the same task. For na-adjectives, it turns into な instead of の or である.

Comment: How are you defining "genitive" such that "adnominal copula" is not a form of genitive? A genitive is defined as a noun that modifies another noun... this definitely seems like cases of this.

"adnominal copula" does not generally seem to be applied to Japanese per the interwebs...

Comment: @virmaior A copula is not a noun, so of course the adnominal copula is not genitive. But, I should have been more specific: I do not think the の there is a genitive *case marker*, I think it's a copula . It's possible to classify it as the genitive case marker with appositive semantics, but that's not where it comes from historically and I think it's more confusing to think of it as such (for the same reason one doesn't consider the copula at the end of the sentence to be a genitive case marker).

Comment: I'm really not grasping how you are using the term "copula" here...

copula is defined as that which links subject and predicate. It's pretty hard to see how 三階建て の 家 represents a subject and a predicate... it seems to be nominalized clause modifying a noun... not a subject and a predicate.

Comment: @virmaior Do you consider the である in 三階建てである家 to be a copula?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie in that case it would be rendered literaly in English as The one built with three levels is the house. And we  could say である is a copula.

But 三階建ての家 seems to be "the three-level built house" at least on first glance which sounds like a pretty normal textbook use of the genitive as I understand the term.

What I'm really asking is if you have a reference that recommends using the word "copula" in these contexts / how you're defining "genitive"

Comment: @virmaior I think your literal translations are bogus. The reason I call it the adnominal copula is because that is what it was historically and I think it aids understandability of its function and paints a simpler picture of the language as a whole.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I'm still not hearing an answer as to where you are getting your terminology from... I'm not trying to say that you're wrong; I'm trying to understand where you are getting your terms from.

Literal translations are in general bogus ... because translations cannot be literal. Care to specify which part I'm failing to literally render?

Comment: @virmaior I would literally translate both as "house which is three stories tall". の was historically the adnominal form of the defective OJ copula に -- you can look this up, but here's a link: http://www.engl.polyu.edu.hk/research/nomz/pdf/WRONA_History_of_NO.pdf

Comment: Okay, that's very helpful for me to get where you are coming from. Etymologically I can see what you are saying. Should we then call the English word "the" a demonstrative pronoun? Or "a" a defective version of the word "one"?

Comment: @virmaior I can say nothing about what "we" should do. Also, I have not thought about English grammar deeply enough to present an even remotely simple framework for it.

Comment: @virmaior The difference is that の can replace である synchronically with the same function, so it can be construed as a form of である (or else as a functional equivalent in certain circumstances, depending on how you'd like to look at it).

Answer (score 2):

See if this helps.

What the person bought was a house. And it's described with a lot of modifiers.

Original:
私は、去年、名古屋市内の静かな所にある庭つきの三階建ての窓の大きい住みやすい家を買いました。

chop out most of the modifiers:

私は、去年、住みやすい家を買いました。Last year I bought a comfortable house.(住みやすい is certainly 'easy to live in', but we don't usually say that in English. I prefer 'comfortable')

Here's the part I chopped out:

名古屋市内の静かな所にある庭つきの三階建ての窓の大きい

Let's add line-breaks

1. 名古屋市内の静かな所にある
2. 庭つきの
3. 三階建ての
4. 窓の大きい

If it helps to understand, add 'house to each of the modifiers.

1. 名古屋市内の静かな所にある(家）...a house in a quiet area of Nagoya
2. 庭つきの(家）...a house with a garden
3. 三階建ての(家）...a three-story house
4. 窓の大きい(家）...a house with big windows.

Of course since they all modify the same noun, we can just recompile them into one sentence.
I prefer to put it in a natural English order than strict order of the Japanese sentence, so long as all the info is contained it shouldn't matter.

"Last year I bought a three-story house in a quiet area of Nagoya with big windows and a garden."

Answer (score 0):

SSB has given you a comprehensive answer and you have some translations but I would like to add an alternative way to compare to English grammar.

Do you know the poem "This is the house that Jack built"? Its starts off with that simple sentence, and then modifies it umpteen times. The grammar you are looking at works in a similar way:

> This is the malt that lay in the house that Jack built.
>
> This is the rat that ate the malt
> That lay in the house that Jack built.
>
> This is the cat that killed the rat
> That ate the malt that lay in the house that Jack built.

For the full story go to:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Is_the_House_That_Jack_Built

Quote:

[This narrative technique] is a cumulative tale that does not tell the story of Jack's house, or even of Jack who built the house, but instead shows how the house is indirectly linked to other things and people, and through this method tells the story of "The man all tattered and torn", and the "Maiden all forlorn", as well as other smaller events, showing how these are interlinked.

Comment: This might be better suited as a comment to the question itself, as it doesn't really answer the question being asked.