# What doesての mean in this context i can't find it anywhere

Tags: grammar

[跡地]{あとち}には[地上]{ちじょう}36[階]{かい}[建]{だ}てのビルが[建]{た}てられる[予定]{よてい}です。

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/83731/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66337/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/13701/9831

Comment: `What does ての mean`-- You don't seem to be parsing the sentence correctly. I suggest you look up [建]{だ}て: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BB%BA%E3%81%A6_%28%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A6%29/#jn-137518　「８枚[切]{ぎ}りのパン」はわかります？

Answer (score 1):

x階建て means x story.
So 36階建ての means 36-storied.
If you read 地下２階(建て)地上４階建てのビル,　it means the building has 4 floors above the ground and 2 basement floors besides.