# Understanding ただより高いものはない

Tags: grammar, set-phrases, reading-comprehension, particle-より, proverbs

> 「むかしっからなァ、ただより高いものはないっていうことわざがあるんだぞっ。」
>   From the old days there's a saying that "nothing costs as much as what is given to us".

I've taken the translation of ただより高いものはない straight from the dictionary, but I can't get this meaning when I analyse the sentence. I read something like "compared to expensive things there are no free things" (obviously nonsense).

Can the sentence be analysed grammatically such that it has the intended meaning? I can't make it work. Or must I just accept that it is a set phrase and move on?

Perhaps a separate question but I'll try asking anyway: 
I wasn't sure about my translation of むかしっからなァ. In particular why there is a っ in it.

Comment: It sounds like you're mistaking which word より binds to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ただより高いものはない is a proverb that means "Nothing is more expensive than free things." In other words, it says free things can be the most costly/risky thing because there is usually some catch for a free offer.

This sentence follows the basic grammar of comparing two things in Japanese:

- 高い: expensive
- **ただより**高い: more expensive **than (being) free**
- ただより高い**もの**: **a thing that is** more expensive than (being) free
- ただより高いもの**はない**: **there is not** a thing that is more expensive than (being) free

Here ただ is not a conjunction nor an adverb but a noun ([*no*-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2771/5010)) that means *free*. ～より is not an adverb but a particle similar in purpose to English "than ～".

昔っから is just a colloquial pronunciation of 昔から, which sounds masculine and dashing. The っ at the end of the sentence is for the same purpose. This accent is typically heard in so-called "Tokyo dialect" (aka [江戸訛り/べらんめえ口調](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%9F%E6%88%B8%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89)).

Comment: I see. Thanks. I think I was confused by the lack of a word like もっと. I guess this is the implied default option.