# 初めてです, is '初めて' an adverb?

Tags: adverbs

I saw following quotes:

```
アメリカは初めてです。 
This is my first time to America.
```

I've learned about `<n.> は <n.|adj.> です`. Checking at several dictionaries, '初めて' is an adverb. Is it OK to use an adverb in `<n.> は <adv.> です`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you cannot attach です to an adverb. But 初めて is **both** an adverb and no-adjective. (A no-adjective is a special type of noun that is semantically similar to an English adjective. See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2770/5010).) You can confirm this fact in [jisho.org's entry](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%88%9D%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6). For example, you can say 初めてのアメリカ, which means "(my) first (trip to) America".

(Similar things happen all the time also in English; *fast* as in "this train is fast" is an adjective, but *fast* as in "this train runs fast" is an adverb.)

Comment: （関係なかったらすいません。）明鏡には「副詞によっては、『～の』を伴って連体修飾をしたり、『～だ』を伴って述語となるものがある（「さすがの僕も」「もうあっぷあっぷだ」）...」と書いてあって、また[ここのページ](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E6%B4%BB%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E8%87%AA%E7%AB%8B%E8%AA%9E/%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E-1-%E6%80%A7%E8%B3%AA%E3%81%A8%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8D/)では「副詞の働き ④ 「だ」「です」などの付属語がついて述語になる。...  彼の家までもうすぐだ。あの人は、昔からそうです。」とか書いてあるんですけど、関係ないんでしょうか。。。

Comment: 「まだです」「まだの人」「すぐの仕事」「そうか」「もっと東」などなど、副詞とされつつ微妙な例は探すと一杯あるようですね…。ただ「初めて」に関しては名詞的性質がかなり強いので no-adj と言っちゃっていい気がします。「初めてはいつですか」とかも言えますし。

Comment: "no-adjective" よりも、単なる名詞のでは？小学館の国語大辞典によりますと、名詞であるような定義が書いてありますが。

Comment: 日本語で書かれた国語辞典にはそもそも "no-adjective" という分類自体[存在しません](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2770/5010)ので、名詞になっているのは何もおかしくないと思います。

Comment: @naruto, ご説明ありがとうございます。^_^