# How to join a noun and a verb

Tags: word-choice

How does one join a noun and a verb? Example:

友達に行かせるのは初めて**で**最後にするわ - This is the first and last time I will let my friend force me to go

I used で to join the noun 初めて and 最後 in the example above, but it doesn't sound too right because で is used to join nouns only. Question is, what is the correct word to use here?

Comment: You've given your question a title that references joining "a noun and a verb," but in the question itself you correctly refer to 初めて as a noun. (It's actually both an adverb and a special type of noun that is sometimes called a "no-adjective" in English – see naruto's answer and the back-and-forth between naruto and others in the comments here https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65765/初めてです-is-初めて-an-adverb). Of course, 最後 is also a noun. I think 初めてで最後 is OK for "first and last time," but this is not an example of joining a noun and a verb.

Comment: I'd thought 最後にする is the verb here

Comment: The verb is just する, and it’s being used in the sense of “to make X [be] Y” – as in “I’m going to make [this] the first and last time…” (And speaking of verbs, 友達に行かせる doesn’t really mean “let a friend force me to go.”)

Comment: `let my friend force me to go` -- Maybe you meant to write 「友達に行か**され**るのは」(*lit.* I'm forced to go by a friend)? `初めてで最後にする` -- I think 最初で最後にする would be more natural.

Comment: Wouldn't [sentences with「最初で最後」](https://ejje.weblio.jp/sentence/content/%22%E6%9C%80%E5%88%9D%E3%81%A7%E6%9C%80%E5%BE%8C%22) be more appropriate as examples for your question? I think it would sound more natural in Japanese to say something along the lines of "I will never let my friend force me to go again" or something.

Answer (score 1):

初めてで最後 may be grammatical but doesn't make much sense to me. The expression you need is **最初で最後**.

- [ALC: 最初で最後](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%9C%80%E5%88%9D%E3%81%A7%E6%9C%80%E5%BE%8C&ref=sa)
- [これが最初で最後になると思います。って英語でなんて言うの？](https://eikaiwa.dmm.com/uknow/questions/10431/)

> ～するのは最初で最後にする。
> I'll make this the first and last time I ～.

(But judging form the English version, you probably wanted to use causative-**passive** 友達に行かせられるのは / 友達に行かされるのは.)