# 決めることに賛成です Ni particle

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

私としては、多数決で決めることに賛成です。 in this sentence why did we use に particle before 賛成です. is 賛成 here working as a noun or adjective ?

Answer (score 3):

This 賛成 is a noun known as a [*no-adjective*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2770/5010). A no-adjective is a noun that translates to an English adjective. Unlike ordinary nouns, no-adjectives and na-adjectives can be modified by adverbs (e.g., やや, かなり, とても) and adverbial expressions, which includes ～に.

Similar examples:

- この曲は若者に人気です。
  This song is popular among young people.
- 若者に人気の曲
  a song that is popular among young people
- この風習は日本に特有です。
  This custom is unique to Japan.
- これは日本に特有の風習です。
  This is a custom that is unique to Japan.

賛成 also works as a plain (suru-)verb:

- 多数決で決めることに賛成します。

Comment: Minor quibble: I'm not familiar with any sort of adjectival usage for 賛成【さんせい】. All monolingual Japanese resources that I have access to describe most other の adjectives like 本当【ほんとう】 as 形動【けいどう】, short for 形容動詞【けいようどうし】, the formal name for な and many の adjectives. Meanwhile, 賛成 is listed as （名）スル, that is, a 名詞【めいし】 or noun that can also be used as a する verb, a category which also includes things like 勉強【べんきょう】 or 料理【りょうり】. (Including extra detail for other readers. :) )

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi You can say その意見に賛成の人 (or sometimes even 意見に賛成な人). While you can also say その意見へ**の**賛成を得る, I don't know why 賛成 can be directly modified by ～に if it's just an ordinary noun.

Comment: 拒否【きょひ】, 屈服【くっぷく】, 意義【いぎ】, 同意【どうい】, etc. all seem to work similarly to 賛成【さんせい】: the "something" noun is marked by に, and the verbal noun can then take either だ・です or some variant of する. I don't think these other words are adjectives either, but perhaps there's a native-speaker perspective that I'm missing...?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi 同意 is indeed similar to 賛成 in that you can say both 彼に同意です and 彼に同意の人. I doubt the other three are similar to 賛成 (×彼に拒否だ, ×彼に屈服の人, ...).

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to naruto's post, think about the meaning of 賛成: *"agreement"*.  As a noun, it can be used in the sense of *"agreement to / with something"*.  As a verb with する, it becomes *"to agree to / with something"*.  Much like the how the English terms *"agreement"* and *"agree"* are used, where one *agrees* or *is in agreement **to** or **with** something*, the Japanese requires a **に** to mark the "something" that serves as the indirect object of this verbal noun or verb construction.

Let's look again at your sample sentence.

> 私【わたし】としては、多【た】数【すう】決【けつ】で決【き】めること​**[に]【●】​賛【さん】成【せい】です**。

Here's one possible translation.

> As for me, I **am in agreement** **[with]{●●●●}** deciding by majority vote.

Note the parallel between the **に** in Japanese and the **with** in the English.  More natural phrasing in English might say something like,

> For my part, I **agree [that]{●●●●}** we should decide by majority vote

... in which case the **に** would align with the **that**.