# Can I say 「車の速度はどのぐらいですか」 instead of 「車はどのぐらい速いですか」

Tags: untagged

Since this sentence,

> 富士山の高さはどれくらいですか?

I found [here](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/japanese-time-duration.html), is correct I figured instead of saying 「車はどのぐらい速いですか」I could just go and say:

> 車の速度はどのぐらいですか

I'm guessing that putting the noun "speed" 「速度」as a noun possesed by car 「車」then I can direct どのぐらい to ask for the speed of the car or simply say "How fast is the car?"

Do you think I'm right for arranging the sentence like so?

Comment: Not really "possessed" but more categorized (see e.g. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2770). I don't see anything wrong with your idea, but I'm not skilled enough to say it authoritatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 車はどのぐらい速いですか and 車の速度はどのぐらいですか are both correct. The differences are:

- The former sounds more informal since 速い is a wago and 速度 is a kango.
- The former gives the impression that you're expecting the car to be fast, whereas the latter comes off as a neutral question about its speed.