# What does 問題の mean in this sentence?

Tags: particle-の, reading-comprehension

[image]

> 問題の神社にも岩座があったっていうし
> The stone like socle in the shrine.

What does 問題の add? My take would be something like "The shrine in question"

Answer (score 2):

The [問題](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C/#jn-220806) is used in the following sense.

> ４ 世間が関心をよせているもの。話題。「―の議員」

I think *in question* is fine. Another alternative is *under discussion*.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I actually didn't realize `問題` had the meaning mentioned in sundowner's answer. That seems more likely, although certainty would require more context.

The Japanese `の` for connecting nouns is really flexible, and [can mean quite a few different things based on context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2771/7705). In this case, it's talking about the `shrine which is the problem`. You could also write this as something like `問題である神社` or `問題になっている神社`; the most natural english translation I can think of is `the problem shrine`.

Incidentally, I'm not sure if the quote in your answer was intended to be a translation, but `問題の神社にも岩座があったっていうし` is something like `They say there was a stone socle in the problem shrine as well`.