Is “日本” a no-adjective?
I've seen some arguments and discussions somewhere that wondered whether “日本” unlike “普通” is not a no-adjective despite “日本の会社” obviously to be translated as “Japanese company” and simply a genitive noun. The arguments I read was:

“あの会社は日本だ” while grammatical “felt” different from “あの会社は普通だ”, how true is this and how would one naturally use “日本の” conclusively? Would one simply say “あの会社は日本のだ。”?
Supposedly “普通” can be used adverbially as in “普通に” while “日本に” as an adverb makes no sense but to be fair “Japanesely” doesn't in English either so it might just be the semantics.
“普通” can be modified by adverbs and “とても普通の会社” is fine while “とても日本の会社” was supposedly not.
“日本” can be modified by adnominal clauses and “我が日本の会社” can have “我が” modify “日本” whereas in “和が普通の会社” it modifies “会社”.

How true is all this and does anyone know of any more tests that could supposedly prove or disprove that “日本の” functions fundamentally differently from “普通の” and that the former is a true noun used as a genitive and the latter a no-adjective?

Would it help you conceptually to swap out 日本 for another noun?  For instance, 犬 works syntactically / grammatically the same as 日本 in your examples, and 犬 similarly cannot sensibly be used as a に adverb.

@EiríkrÚtlendi well that's what I'm wondering with this post, evidently “普通” or “永遠” do not work that way so I wonder to what degree the arguments that “日本” is a noun, not an adjective, are correct.

@EiríkrÚtlendi Whether adverbs related to countries or languages are possible seems to be language-specific. In English language, there are adverbs Englishly, Japanesely, Latinly. In Latin language, there are adverbs anglicē, latīnē.

I'm not really sold on the idea that "no-adjective" is a natural or useful category (despite asking https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/ so many years ago). Every noun can be used this way. The real distinction is whether noun + に functions as a 副詞.

@KarlKnechtel Some argument for distinction of no-adjectives from normal nouns was that, in Japanese language, no-adjectives (like other types of adjectives) cannot be used as e.g. subjects (i.e. with が particle) or direct objects (i.e. with を particle). (Such limitation is not crosslinguistically universal, and adjectives can be used in all functions of nouns in languages like Latin and Slavic languages.)

@Arfrever, I recognize that words like "Englishly" exist, albeit as uncommon corner cases.  That said, these are also all unambiguously adjectives in English. Meanwhile, 日本 or 犬 are not, and thus cannot be sensibly used as adverbs (without other elements, such as のように or らしく, etc.).

@Arfrever Ah, true. 永遠は。。。 doesn't work, just like how "na-adjectives" may require a 〜さ suffix for such use.

@KarlKnechtel, I do see examples of 永遠が in a subject role, and 永遠 is listed in dictionaries as both 形動 and 名. Meanwhile, 静か or あばら do not appear to have any noun-ish classification or syntax.

@EiríkrÚtlendi I don't know that we can really reason here from what English does at all, because English is accustomed to using words "as" a different part of speech from normal. It's not clear whether to analyze this as some kind of "null inflection" that allows for using the word that way, or if it really just intrinsically has both semantics. (I.e.: i-stems of Japanese verbs might serve as nouns with irregular meanings, but at least you actually have to inflect to that form. In English we can "go for a walk", "have a drink" etc.)

@KarlKnechtel, English is quite flexible at verbing nouns etc.  That said, if a word can be used adverbially, and is a derivative and not just inherently an adverb, it derives from an adjective — in both English and Japanese.  We cannot say "Japanly" or "dogly" as adverbs, except in deliberate contravention of grammatical rules. Similarly, we cannot say 日本に or 犬に as adverbs. In English, if you add "-ly" to form an adverb, it must be added to an adjective. In Japanese, if you add に to form an adverb, it must be added to a 形容動詞. Since 日本に is not an adverb, we can say that 日本 is not a 形容動詞. No?

@EiríkrÚtlendi I would say that virtually all no-adjectives are also nouns but I did recall some counter examples being brought up whereas many, but not nearly all na-adjectives are also nouns, but most nouns are certainly neither na adjectives nor no-adjectives. “永遠” is both. I'm interested in whether “日本” is a no-adjective as well because it heavily occurs as “日本の” of course and Japanese seems to lack an adjective that says “Japanese” to begin with, if this not be it. But that's all nothing unusual, English lacks a noun that means “Japanese person”, the same way it has say “Dane”.

@EiríkrÚtlendi I think it's not a full argument though since some no-adjectives such as “病気” also don't really occur as adverbs, and of course “Japanese” in English is clearly an adjective, but “Japanesely” feels odd, simply because the semantics don't make sense. I'd say that if something can be used as an adverb, it's clearly an adjective, but the converse need not hold.

@Zorf, the fact that 病気 cannot be used as an adverb, isn't that more an argument that it is not an adjective, and that cases of 病気の should be analyzed as attributive use of a noun? I honestly think that parsing 病気の as an "adjective" is an English-y way of looking at things, influenced by the English adjective "sick".

While so-called no-adjectives are syntactically very close to nouns, words in this category often exhibit adjective-like qualities, and lack noun-like qualities.

Many no-adjectives are modified not by an adjective but by an adverb:

やや緑色の服, 全く普通の人, 明らかに唯一の選択肢, 実に多くの意見


Many no-adjectives can be adverbialized by using に (≈ -ly):

普通に歩く, 永遠に生き続ける, ピンク色に光る, 真に有効な薬, 抜群に良い成績, 無限に増える (exceptions: 益々増える)


Many no-adjectives cannot take を or が:

×普通を, ×真を, ×抜群を, ×無限を  (exceptions: 永遠を生きる, 普通が一番だ)


Some no-adjectives have na-adjective equivalents with almost the same meaning:

抜群の/抜群な, 適度の/適度な, 最悪の/最悪な



Even experts seem undecided on how to categorize these words since there are many exceptions. Regarding the difference from na-adjectives, this article points out that no-adjectives tend to describe categorical or extreme qualities, while na-adjectives tend to describe quantitative qualities; in other words, no-adjectives typically cannot be modified by とても or 少し.
Anyway, regarding your question, 日本 doesn't fit any of these conditions, so I believe it's simply a noun. We can say 彼は日本だ meaning "He is in Japan", but this is a different problem. While no-adjectives are typically translated into English adjectives (green, normal, obvious, ...), it may not be a good idea to regard this as a definitive criterion.

Might you also share how you would naturally formulate the conclusive form of “日本の” as in “This company is Japanese.”?

@Zorf I doubt you can do that. Normally, it's just この会社は日本の会社だ :)
